# Регистр первой буквы на UTF8

Tags: php, utf-8

Как правильно и коротко привести к верхнему регистру первую букву в русском UTF-8 тексте в PHP?

Comment: [Только первый символ](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) [Все первые символы в строке](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) [UTF-8 вариации](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php)

Answer (score 7):

```
  $string = "привет";
  $char = mb_strtoupper(substr($string,0,2), "utf-8"); // это первый символ
  $string[0] = $char[0];
  $string[1] = $char[1];
  echo $string;
```

Comment: Надо в строке UPCASE для первой буквы, я просто написал неправильно наверно.

Comment: В чем проблема не пойму, что не работает???

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
function mb_strtoupper_first($str, $encoding = 'UTF8')
{
    return
        mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($str, 0, 1, $encoding), $encoding) .
        mb_substr($str, 1, mb_strlen($str, $encoding), $encoding);
}
```

Отличается от ответа he11d0g тем, что в `mb_substr` передается длина строки (при передаче null не работает с кодировкой cp1251 на php5.3)

Answer (score 2):

Я пользуюсь ucfirst. Товарищ ROOT дал ссылку на документацию.

Comment: ucfirst не работает с русским UTF
mb_convert_case - умеет делать заглавными все слова с тексте, а вот только первую ну никак не победить, можно конечно выдернуть кусок, его поднять  в регистре и посадить обратно, но я хочу по простому, а не просто решить проблему.

Comment: Упс, извини, плохо прочитал вопрос. Тебе нужно именно первую букву в строке, или каждое слово в строке?

Answer (score 2):

Так же добавлю - примитивный способ)))

```
$string = 'я строчко';
$string = str_replace($string[0], strtoupper($string[0]), $string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: strtoupper для utf-8 по моему нужно использовать mb_strtoupper

Comment: Что за PHP такой. ни strtoupper ни mb_strtoupper не переводят русские буквы в верхний регистр, английские переводит нормально

Comment: спасибо отработало "строчко" отлично

Answer (score 1):

```
function upFirstLetter($str, $encoding = 'UTF-8')
{
    return mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($str, 0, 1, $encoding), $encoding)
    . mb_substr($str, 1, null, $encoding);
}

upFirstLetter('какой-то текст');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "привет мир";  
list($str[0], $str[1]) = mb_strtoupper($str[0].$str[1], 'UTF8');  
echo $str;
```